# Check <li> href attribute and compare with url index of

Tags: jquery

when this page loads by copy/paste http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1

Get list of li "a" href values and check value exists. Compare href value & url indexof value. If exists success..otherwise no.

please provide me a suggestion or solution to proceed further.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="slist selected" id="id1"><a href="#!id10">Test1/a></li>
    <li class="slist" id="id2"><a href="#!id20">Test2</a></li>
    <li class="slist" id="id3"><a href="#!id30">Test3/a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('ul li').each(function(i)
{
    var listIDs = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('listIDs') > -1) {
        console.log(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: basically you want to list in a variable all the links that refer to the current anchor (or url params)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting what you tried:

```
$('ul li').each(function (i) {
    var listIDs = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(listIDs) > -1) { //there should not be quote.
        console.log(1);
    }
});
```

And the solution will be just checking the element by the attribute selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = "#!" + window.location.href.split("!")[1];
    if ($("ul li a[href='" + id + "']").length) {
        console.log("present");    
    } else {    
        console.log("absent")
    }
});
```

Comment: @K k.. Thanks for your solution.. by getting... Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul li a[href=#!id1]